# Use a custom template field even if it's excluded from display

Tags: 7, views

In a Views, I have two field :

- Link field : With 1 to n links to display (excluded from display)
- Body field : Who use the previous link field (via rewrite output and token)

I have created a custom template for display link field like I want.

Here is my problem:
When I render my Views, my custom template isn't used for display my links...
He use the display function defined in the link field settings.

Is there a way to force View to use my template ?
Any suggestions to do this?

Edit : Some screenshot of fields and theme informations

Link field :
[image]

Body field :
[image]

Theme Infos :
[image]

Comment: I'm trying to solve the same problem.  What was your solution? It seems fields used as replacement patterns simply cannot be themed.

Answer (score 0):

To use the custom template for a particular field you should use the template suggestion from **Theme:Information** from advance section of your view, Select the suggestion template form the them info as the screenshot for field NID
[image] . Create that template inside the your_theme/template folder. Don't forgot to clear the drupal cache.

Comment: Thank for your answer but I have already do this solution. Maybe my post is not clear on that point but I have a custom template acccording Theme:Information infos.

I have clean my cache many times... But the problem stay...

Use a custom template on a hidden field seems doesn't work.

Comment: if it is hidden then why you want to theme that, i unable to understand in this point.

Comment: Because I use it in an other field where I rewrite output using this field with a token.

Comment: so you should theme that another field than only it will effect...debug the $output or available templete variables to theme your field

Answer (score 0):

If you make this field the displayed field it will take the theme adjustments. Do your rewrite and replacement patters on this field, put it at the end of the field list and exclude the others.  If this field is used as a replacement pattern the theme will not be applied.